# Unable to receive recipient view url of docusign

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rest, docusignapi

I am using docusign_rest gem. I am creating template with

```
create_template
```

method and envelope with

```
create_envelope_from_template
```

method.
But when I was trying to retrieving the url for embedded signing with the help of following code

```
client = DocusignRest::Client.new
@url = client.get_recipient_view(
envelope_id: @envelope_response["envelopeId"],
name: 'some_name',
email: 'some_email',
return_url: 'http://google.com'
)
```

then it returning nil. So I am unable to generate url.

When I am using the iodocs portal of docusign for the same POST request

Recipient v2/accounts/:accountId/envelopes/:envelopeId/views/recipient

```
{
"authenticationMethod": "email",
"email": "some_email",
"returnUrl": "www.gmail.com",
"userName": "some_name",
"clientUserId": "some_email"
}
```

I get the url as required.

So am I doing something incorrect in the ruby gem's call or is there a bug?

Comment: Any chance you can get the actual JSON that's being sent? I am not a ruby guy and want to rule out Gem vs DocuSign API issues.

Comment: I agree that posting the actual JSON that your Ruby gem is sending out in the request would be helpful here in determining where the problem lies, please post this...

Answer (score 2):

user2593706 : this will return nil because u r not passing any value @envelope_response["envelopeId"] so u need to pass the envelope id which is created previously or any other u want to get response. in rails its very easy to implement... if u want to look at response from docusign u need to use your terminal for that.. do this...

```
        1. rails c 
        2. paste your create_template method code as yours
        3. paste your create_envelope_from_template code
        4. then run immediately your code 

       client = DocusignRest::Client.new
       @url = client.get_recipient_view(
        envelope_id: @envelope_response["envelopeId"],
        name: 'some_name',
        email: 'some_email',
        return_url: 'http://google.com'
       )
```

then u will get ur response.... hope this works. and its really good to do this task

Answer (score 1):

To use embedding functionality for a given envelope, you need to set the clientUserId property at the time the envelope is being created, then you reference it again with the same value when requesting the URL (just like you have in your code).

This page from the DocuSign Dev Center explains it in more detail:

http://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/features/embedding-docusign

Comment: We did set the clientUserId property at the time of creating the envelope. We know this for sure since when we tested on the iodocs link, whenever we gave a clientUserId that was different from the email (that's how the gem works), we were getting an error in the response instead of the url.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is an issue with the Ruby gem and not a bug in the DocuSign platform, since I'm able to get embedded signing (and sending) to work just fine in PHP and other languages.